# Узнать индекс элемента контейнера

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++17

Хочу написать параллельный `for_each`, но внутри мне нужно знать индекс текущего обрабатываемого элемента. Как его узнать без `data race`?

```
std::vector<int> some_container;
//... init
std::for_each(std::execution::par, some_container.begin(),
                                   some_container.end(), 
                                   [](int curr) {
                                      // auto curr_index = ???
                                      // ...
                                   }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::vector<int> some_container;
//... init
std::for_each(std::execution::par, some_container.begin(),
                                   some_container.end(), 
                                   [&](const int& curr) {
                                      auto curr_index = &curr - some_container.data();
                                      // ...
                                   }
);
```

---

Более продвинутые варианты - использовать современные библиотеки [`range-v3`](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/), 
 которые, однако, несовместимы с `std::for_each`. Дело в том, что **код ниже не будет работать** из-за того, что `std::begin(indexed_data)` и `std::end(indexed_data)` имеют разный тип. Впрочем, код выглядел бы так:

```
using namespace ranges;

std::set<int> my_data = ...;
auto indexed_data = view::zip(my_data, view::iota(0));

std::for_each(std::execution::par, 
                               std::begin(indexed_data),
                               std::end(indexed_data), 
                               [&](const auto& p) {
                                   auto&& [data, curr_index] = p;
                                  // ...
                               }
);
```

Но если захочется использовать не-параллельную версию, то запросто:

```
ranges::for_each(indexed_data, 
      [&](const auto& p) {
          auto&& [data, curr_index] = p;
          // ...
      }
);
```

Comment: понял, а если контейнер `std::set`, то это не будет работать?

Comment: @николай не будет, только для контейнеров, которые лежат в памяти непрерывно (`std::array`, `std::vector`)

Comment: желательно, чтобы для всех контейнеров работало. Может есть другой способ?

Comment: Используйте std::distance вместо вычетания , https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance , но помните, что для std::set::itertator сложность будет линейной.

Comment: @Chorkov не сработает, в `std::for_each` приходит значение, а не итератор. @николай добавил более продвинутый пример в ответ

Comment: @николай, в других контейнерах нет понятия индекса, поэтому подобный запрос не имеет смысла.

Comment: Нет смысла городить огород с `zip`, достаточно просто `iota`, т.е. для `for_each` нужен захват исходного массива и пробежаться по индексам; нет смысла в паре [элемент, индекс]